# Prove a real-valued function is monotonic if it is continuous on an open interval and has no local extremes

Tags: real-analysis

My approach is to assume that $f$ is not monotonic and then construct a local extreme by using the fact that $f$ attains its extreme values on a compact set. I can assume that  $\exists c\lt\delta$ with $f(c)\gt f(\delta)$ (or equal). I can do something similar with the fact that $f$ is not decreasing. Still, aside some a vague vision of a torturous proof by cases, I'm stuck. I have a feeling that this proof can be done in a simple way that I am missing. Could someone give me a hint? Assure me that there is a simple proof of this?

Comment: I've spent many hours and seem to have proved this without assuming the existence of the three points. I (hopefully) proved that $f$ must be increasing or decreasing on any compact subset of $(a,b)$ and then that $f$ could not be increasing on one interval and decreasing on another. Mostly I worked by contradiction, constructing local extreme values. I would have checked this question answered, but I feel that proof of the lemma used (not offered here but attempted by me) was more complicated than the proof attained via the lemma.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: This is the older Question, but I'm sure you noticed that.  I think it gives the more concise argument.

Comment: @hardmath See the comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875976/a-continuous-function-that-attains-neither-its-minimum-nor-its-maximum-at-any-op#comment1807413_875976). (And also my comment just above it.)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f$ is not monotone on the interval $(a,b)$. Then there exists three points $a<x<y<z<c$ such that, without loss of generality, $f(x)<f(y)$ and $f(z)<f(y)$. Now consider the restriction of $f$ to the closed interval $[x,z]$. As you say, $f$, being continuous on $[x,z]$, must attain a maximum there. Can it be attained at $x$ or at $z$? What does that tell you?

Comment: Would you mind formally explaining how we can get those three points? I can see two pairs, one for each negation, but not how to get three simply. Once I get the three points clear, I think I can do the rest according to your advice.

Comment: what does it mean for a function not to be monotone?

Comment: There exist two points as a counterexample, a pair for the negation of increasing and a pair for the negation of decreasing. I don't see how to simply get at the three points without a bunch of cases as far as their order goes.

Comment: Intuitively I see the three points should exists, of course, but the negation of monotonicity just gives me two, as far as I can see. If you can help me out with a lemma, that would be great.