# Function with no maximum or minimum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Can anyone give an example of a function that is continuous on (0,1] but that does not have a maximum or a minimum on (0,1].

Comment: Consider any monotonic function on $(0,1]$.

Comment: @JannikPitt A monotonic function will have a maximum or a minimum at 1.

Comment: @DougM But only one of these (if it isn't constant).

Comment: The OP didn't explain whether a local or global extremum is meant.  If the latter see Gibbs' response below.  But if the former,  see [A continuous function that attains neither its minimum nor its maximum at any open interval is monotone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875976/a-continuous-function-that-attains-neither-its-minimum-nor-its-maximum-at-any-op).

Answer (score 4):

Take the restriction to that interval of $\frac{1}{x}\sin \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: man, creative.  Wish I thought of it.